# mvc 4.5 many to one create using http post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with MVC displaying list of many to one objects using an http post.  How do I perform a `db.SaveChanges()` so that it includes each claw from my form submit?

example primary entity:
Cats table has

```
Cats: id, and cat name only.
```

many to one cat entity (notice CatId):

```
Paws: Paw Number, claw1, claw2, claw3, claw4, claw5, and finally CatId
```

each claw number represents a sharpness index.

On my main form I have only a single cat and have all 4 paws and its sharpness index listed out.

Now if I want to save each of the 4 paws and claws for this one cat how do I get save `db.SaveChanges()` if there is no it pointing to `Paws` in the `Cats` table.  This seems so basic but haven't been able to tweak it yet.   I've even set the `@Html.ForEditor` control to have an id of `Paws` and even `Paws.Claws` or `Paws.Claw` doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to use MVC 4.5 for this.

Comment: Many-to-one relationships are usually "managed" on the *many* side - in your case in the `Paw` entity. Setting the owning `Cat` (or its ID) for each `Paw` should work. The paws might not necessarily be visible from the Cat side of the relationship until you reload it from the context though - I'm not sure whether EF does this automagically.

Comment: Also, consider improving your question a little. Use inline code formatting, and instead of an ad-hoc description of your entities, use C# classes or SQL. Same for what you've tried - use code, simplified as much as possible, instead of prose.

Comment: So I should db.SaveChanges first, then some how retrieve that Cat's Id?  How would do I get the Cats Id after doing a db.SaveChanges?  Also how do I get each of the entity for each Paw after I do that and then do another db.SaveChanges? thx

Comment: Is your issue that you can't get the model binding to work in your post action or that you aren't sure how to structure your entities in your model (I'm assuming EF from `db.SaveChanges()`)?

Comment: I think the structure is correct, but the problem is I just can't get the binding to work since the Cat doesn't have a primary key to all four paws.   Only each Paw has a foreign key to the cat.

Comment: @CyberSluethOmega Yes. That's how many-to-one works. It's the *only* sane way to get many-to-one to work in SQL.

Comment: But my problem is when its time to perform the submit on the paws, the entity framework in my setup doesn't seem to know how to reference the 4 paws... so I'm trying to figure out here how to add the 4 paws, or add a Name that the entity framework can reference so after I save the can I can give each paw a catId and a sharpness index so I can save them too.  I really haven't been able to cross that bridge yet but I absolutely need help in this problem to fix that.